# Scala Lift: How to wrap REST responses into an XML root element?

Tags: xml, rest, scala, lift

I'm doing a project to test Scala and Lift at my company, atm I'm implementing a REST API
that shoves XML around. I saw that there is an XMLApiHelper that offers the createTag method
that encapsulates the responses in a root element.

So I did this

```
object RestAPI extends RestHelper with XMLApiHelper {
  serve {
    …
  }
  …
  def createTag(in: NodeSeq): Elem = <root>{in}</root>
}
```

This does not seem to work. Am I missing something?

Regards,
raichoo

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "does not seem to work" in more detail?  An error message would be a good start...

Comment: It just does not wrap the content into the <root> element. "Does not work" sounds a bit too harsh ^^. I get my xml responses just fine, just lacking the root element defined in createTag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RestHelper` and `XMLApiHelper` are not meant to work together.  They are meant to solve two different kinds of problems.

`XMLApiHelper` defines an implicit conversion between the XML Node Scala types and the LiftResponse class.  `RestHelper` defines a mechanism which will return either `XML` or `JSON` to the client, depending on what they asked for.  `RestHelper` ties into the dispatch process at a lower level than `XMLApiHelper`, so the implicit on `XMLApiHelper` never actually gets called.

If you only want to return `XML` to an HTTP method, use `XMLApiHelper`.  If you want the flexibility to return `XML` or `JSON` depending on how the HTTP method is called, then use the `RestHelper`.